# How to generate an observation matrix from its covariance matrix

Tags: matrices

I would like to know how to generate a matrix $A$ from its covariance matrix whatever the property of this matrix, i.e. correlated or uncorrelated.
Specifically I'm interested to generate a noise matrix that has $\sigma\times I_{n,n}$ as covariance matrix which is uncorrelated. I'm expecting that for both cases either correlated or not the method is the same may be using eigenvalues or the SVD factorization.

Comment: Is that at all like trying to reconstruct a data set from the statistics derived from it?  Please, try to generate the original set of data from its standard deviation and mean, and tell me if this is what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a random-data-matrix $U$ rowwise with means=0 and stddev=1 or as desired with much more columns than rows. The rows should/must truly be uncorrelated.

Then compute the cholesky-factor L of your covariance matrix C such that $ L*L^t=C $ by cholesky-decomposition.
Then compute your sought datamatrix D by $ D = L * U $